# WebSocket library for Android, iOS and Flash

Tags: iphone, android, flash, websocket

can someone please provide an example of WebSocket implementation in Android, iOS(iPhone/iPad) and Flash (not flex!).

I found some libraries but none of that work :). My browser WebSocket implementation is working great using Socket.IO, now I would like to dig also into Android, iPhone and Flash.

I tried to implement a Android webview pointing to a website where sockets are implemented, but it doesn't work. I would be great to have some native library for that.

Thx for your help!

Comment: I recomend this: https://github.com/stellaeof/java-websocket-client

Answer (score 10, accepted):

iOS 4.2 and above have native WebSockets support.

For Android devices with Flash support (or any browser with Flash) you can use [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js). Socket.IO actually includes web-socket-js as one of the transports that can be enabled.

See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets) for an up-to-date list of browsers and mobile devices with native WebSockets support.

**Update**:

For native iOS applications (Objective-C) check out [UnittWebSocketClient](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient). One caveat: I looked in the code and it uses the HyBi-07 version of the protocol which is more recent than the Hixie-76 version currently supported by most browsers. However, if the server you are connecting to supports HyBi-07 or later it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You are talking about browsers right? How about native classes so you don't have to use webview. Browsers are behaviours like touch-hold event that I don't want to have.

Comment: @xpepermint, I've updated the answer to address the native iOS class part of your question.

Answer (score 14):

This is an old thread, but I should point out for iOS, Unitt and other existing iOS WebSocket clients don't support the latest standard.

We just released a WebSocket client called [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket).  (disclaimer: I'm the author)

It supports the latest standard, [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), has no external dependencies, and works with iOS 4.x. It also should be really fast and compliant.  [Passes](http://square.github.com/SocketRocket/results) all of the Autobahn tests too

Answer (score 7):

[jWebSocket](http://code.google.com/p/jwebsocket/) seem to have Android support.

Comment: But it's for native java applications, not web browsers. Plus, Android Browser does not support applets (java shim) nor the full flash system (flash shim) **:(**

Comment: @Christian: It has support for Android apps, they are written in Java. This question is not about web browsers.

Comment: Link no working. 404 error

Answer (score 4):

I realize that it's bad form to respond to such an old thread, but this post keeps showing up in my searches. After research (but without implementing yet), [Autobahn](http://www.tavendo.de/autobahn/clientlibraries.html) seems like the best option for the Android platform by far. Many of the other options use their test suite, a newer draft is supported (protocol 13, draft 14), and I found the project tutorials very helpful.

Comment: unfortunately they don't support wss yet.

Answer (score 2):

For Android native apps, there is Autobahn WebSockets for Android

https://github.com/oberstet/AutobahnAndroid

It supports the final RFC6455, integrates well with UI and service apps, provides RPC and PubSub over WebSockets, and more. Check out the project README on GitHub.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Autobahn.

Comment: Link is broken. Working one as of 09-Oct-2012: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid