# which is better way for websocket protocol? native ios or hybrid or web app?

Tags: iphone, ios, websocket

I am wondering what would be the best way to transfering data from the server to the application.

I am comfortable with javascript so web app would be a good one for publishing websocket communication.

Sending a server data to the browser like safari is easy(web app).

But I am not sure I can send a received data from the browser to my application.

is anybody tried browser to application transfer?

if this is impposible, what do I need to publish websocket connection in ios native app or

hybrid app? I have almost zero knowledge about ios. can you guys suggest good tutorials

for ios and ios websocket?

Answer (score 0):

Using WebSockets from Javascript it is easy to send data from the browser to the server:

```
ws.send(data).
```

WebSocket clients are also available in iOS. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347499/websocket-library-for-android-ios-and-flash) answer.